# How to patch a wood lath plaster rounded corner?

Tags: drywall, painting, plaster, patching-drywall, lath-and-plaster

I am attempting to repair a rounded plaster corner. (Image below).  The plaster was blown out during an electrical re-wire for the bathroom switch pictured.

I’m assuming the wire corner bead runs vertically along the entire corner, floor to ceiling. There are parts of the blowout with no wood.

Question is - what is the PROPER way to repair this? Should I tie in a scrap piece of lath to the existing where it’s missing or can I treat this like a drywall patch and patch in a rectangular piece of drywall with some blocking?

Also, can I use a fast setting compound (20 or 45) and finish with a topping coat of joint compound - or should I use PlasterMagic, or another plaster alternative?

I’ll be painting the entire bathroom after the repairs.

[image: Damaged Plaster Corner]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this got ZERO love, and I have finished the job, figured I would post what I did.

Simply bought some wire mesh from the local home goods store, and screwed it directly into the wood lathe after breaking out the hole a bit more.  That gave me a good base for my 20 minute hot mud to mushroom through.  As for the rounded corner -- it was nothing special, just took a minute or two of using gentle rounding strokes to make it match the existing radius.

In hindsight, probably give it a minute to set a bit more before doing the radius.  Also -- I needed to apply the mud even CLOSER to the outline of the electrical box.  I left it a little shy of the box, and the regular sized plate cover did not cover the hole, and I needed 1 more trip to the store to get a 'JUMBO' cover plate.  Turned out great.

[image: Mesh wire installed...]
[image: Hot Mud applied]
[image: Final finish with paint]

Comment: Good solution. I was just about to write up a cut-it-square-and-fill-with-drywall suggestion. Sorry we missed your request.